# How to avoid led blinking in a while loop state change?

Tags: c++, arm

I have a L476vg development board that I am running the following code for. My objective is to detect the state change with the button but also not have the led blink if I hold down the button. I downloaded several variations of the code but they all seem to not work properly. Can someone point out how to modify the code below so that the led changes states when the button is push and does not change states as a result of holding down the button

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut myLed(LED1);                 //initializing the needed variable 
                                          and pins
DigitalIn myButton(USER_BUTTON);



int main() {

int myState = 0;
int count = 0;
int toggle = 0;


 while (1){

    if (myState != myButton){   //detect change of state
         count ++;              // if state has changed increment the count
         myState != myState;   // record the state change
        toggle = count % 2;    // determin the toggle direction
         if (toggle != 0){     //read the toggle 
           myLed != myLed;}     // if odd toggle the led
         if (toggle = 0){
           myLed = myLed; }    // if even keep same state 

   else
      myLed = myLed;


   }
 } 

}
```

Comment: The expression `myState=! myButton` is an *assignment*. I suppose you mean `myState != myButton`? Some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) should have helped figure it out.

Comment: I'm having trouble following this code. Does `if (toggle != 0) { myLed =! myLed else myLed=myLed; }` compile (an `else` without an `if` inside the braces?)

Comment: Probably need to use a timer, `SysTick` for example.

Comment: overall `while(1)` without `sleep` or `std::condition_variable` 's `.wait_for()`  is bad idea coz cpu going on full load then.

Comment: This code does not compile.  On the 'if' clause, my compiler generates: "error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’:"

Comment: Can you try to re-post the exact code you are using?

Comment: This is what I have modified it to, trying to simplify it but I don't understand why the else statements are causing a problem?

Comment: I updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to point out about this code I think:

- Assignments like `myLed=myLed` do nothing at all.  If you don't assign a new value to a variable then it will keep its existing value.  Remove these to make your code clearer.
- There is no true 'boolean' (true/false) data type in C or C++, despite the presence of the `bool` type. Everything is a number. Unless the documentation tells you otherwise, there is no guarantee that the two values that the `myButton` input can take are the same as the two values to which you are setting `myState`.  Rather than toggling `myState` with `myState=!myState`, it would be safer to set it to mirror the value of the input variable by using e.g. `myState=myButton`.
- It is not clear what your `count` variable is doing.  Are you trying to detect only button presses, and not releases?  If so the most reliable method would be to check the value of `myButton`.
- In response to [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)'s comment, you have changed all occurences of `=!` to `!=` in your question, and this is not correct.  `a=!b` assigns `a` to have the value 'not `b`' (if `b` is true then `a` is false and vice-versa); `a!=b` is a comparison, evaluating to true if `a` and `b` are not equal.  It would probably be a good idea for you to read more about basic C syntax if you're making this kind of error.

If I understand the intent of your code correctly, my suggestion would therefore be:

```
DigitalOut myLed(LED1);
DigitalIn myButton(USER_BUTTON);

int main() {

    int myState = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (myState != myButton) {   // detect change of state
        myState = myButton;          // record the state change
        if (myButton) {              // if the button is down,
            myLed = !myLed;          // toggle the led
        }
    }

}
```

(It is possible that I have misunderstood your requirements though because your question is not particularly clear in this respect.)